# How to send a push Notification (Parse) When a user publish a message Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm new to Android, I'm developing an application which is a little bit similar to WhatsApp, I have different users, and I want when a User send a message, other users should receive a Push Notification.

So when a user add a new message, when a value will be inserted to the class, all the users should receive Push notifications.

I know how to send a push notification from the console, but I want push notifications to be sent automatically.

Thanks

Comment: so need to write a script which takes message from db at partiulcar time and fires the gcm send messgae from server

Comment: Push functionality is well documented by Parse. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Well I couldn't find anything similar to I'm looking, I just an orientation on how can I start to do that, if you don't have the answer to my question you don't have to answer

Comment: You couldn't find anything similar to sending a push notification from parse.com cloud code?  Where have you looked?

Answer (score 1):

You can send push notifications with parse by using channels whereby each user subscribes to a set of channels and you can send pushes to particular channels.

OR

You can use advanced targeting in which you use the installation class to select the devices.

```
 ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> pq = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
              pq.whereEqualTo("area", message3);
              pq.whereEqualTo("group", message2);
              pq.whereNotEqualTo("key", value);
              // Send push notification to query
              ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
              push.setQuery(pq); // Set our Installation query
              push.setMessage("New Message");
              push.sendInBackground();

            Intent in = new Intent(Post.this,Notifications.class);
            progress.dismiss();
            startActivity(in);
```

OR

You can use cloud code to receive the data sent by the user and send push notifications to relevant devices

Comment: if you are using advance targeting , make sure to enable client side push in the settings in parse.